# What does 10 Vols mean?

Tags: terminology, notation, units

I am currently working on a project and the protocol says the following, "Wash resin 3 times 10 vols of the extract buffer." This is very confusing to me and I am not exactly sure what the 10 vols part means. I tried to look it up, however, the few explanations I found were still confusing. I am new to research, and have not been exposed really to the "lingo".

Comment: Some experimental procedures are only good enough to be chucked at the heads of the people who wrote them for inclarity — your’s is an example.

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean "wash resin 3 times **with** 10 vols of the extract buffer".

Vol means **volume strength**. It tells you how much of a certain element *in milliliters* will be RELEASED from a certain substance. In this case, your buffer is supposed to release 10 vol of something. That's all it means.

However, I am surprised about the usage of vol in this context. Volume strength is usually a term directly associated with hydrogen peroxide, and dealing with the release of a certain volume of oxygen.